# Why does card overflow from parent col

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox, bootstrap-4

> My Form elements are not fitting in correctly and the alignment is
>   distorted.

- `.h-100` has been used since the blue back ground is my navigation and I want it to fill the entire height available in the screen.
- I would prefer to accept an answer which can explain why my snippet does not work.

[Plunker here](http://plnkr.co/edit/KLDWTrX3PuBcKQQRFDrz)

HTML

```
  <div class="container-fluid h-100">
          <div class="row h-100">
            <div class="col-2  blue">
            </div>
            <div class="col-10">
             <div class="card h-100">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <form>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="Random">Random 1</label>
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="random1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter name">        
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="Random">Random 2</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="random2" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter name">        
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                          <label for="Random">Random 3</label>
                          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="random3" placeholder="Enter Random">        
                        </div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                          <label for="Random">Random 4</label>
                          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="random4" aria-describedby="employeeCodeHelp" placeholder="Enter random random">        
                        </div>
                    <div class="form-check">
                      <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="isActive">
                      <label class="form-check-label" for="isActive">Is Active</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="Random">Random 5</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="random5" placeholder="Enter Random Random">        
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group">
                          <label for="phoneNumber">Random 6</label>
                          <input type="number" class="form-control" id="random6" placeholder="Enter phone number">        
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="emailId">Email</label>
                            <input type="number" class="form-control" id="emailId" placeholder="Enter email">        
                          </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                  </form>
                </div>
          </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

CSS

```
.blue {
    background-color:blue;
}

html,body {
    height: 100%;
  }
```

Screen shot

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove .h-100 class from .container and from .row as its height should be auto instead of 100% , answer is as per what i understand , that your card is going out of your .col right?
if you want to give blue shape than here is the code :

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-2  blue">
        </div>
        <div class="col-10">
         <div class="card h-100">
            <div class="card-body">
              <form>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="Random">Random 1</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="random1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter name">        
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="Random">Random 2</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="random2" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter name">        
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="Random">Random 3</label>
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="random3" placeholder="Enter Random">        
                    </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="Random">Random 4</label>
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="random4" aria-describedby="employeeCodeHelp" placeholder="Enter random random">        
                    </div>
                <div class="form-check">
                  <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="isActive">
                  <label class="form-check-label" for="isActive">Is Active</label>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="Random">Random 5</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="random5" placeholder="Enter Random Random">        
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="phoneNumber">Random 6</label>
                      <input type="number" class="form-control" id="random6" placeholder="Enter phone number">        
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="emailId">Email</label>
                        <input type="number" class="form-control" id="emailId" placeholder="Enter email">        
                      </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
              </form>
            </div>
      </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

.blue{
 min-height: 100px //the height you want to give
}

Comment: Can you please explain me why my original snippet was not working as expected ? I am not able to understand what actually happened wrong. The fix  you suggested seems to have work. An explanation will help improve the answer.

Comment: height property is used to give fixed height to element  while min-height will set a height that is your minimum requirement , in min-height if your element height increase the height that you specify will exceed min-height and it will change accordingly

Comment: thanks for response cyrus. But the alignment issue is corrected without using the min-height at all. When I removed the container and row h-100.